# In matlab, what is the best way to solve non-negative least squares with a matrix (instead of vector) of variables?

Tags: matlab, constraints, least-squares

I need to solve the following problem using matlab:

```
min_X ||A*X - B||^2
s.t X is a M*N matrix and X>=0
```

where M and N can be upto 10000.

What function and library will provide a fast, scalable solution fot this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check my solution here: [Gradient Descent Matlab implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799435/gradient-descent-matlab-implementation/27810509#27810509) . I have attached an implementation of Linear regression (Least Squares), using my own version of code and a comparison with Matlab's `polyfit` function. Cheers!